# Get a listing of all unique characters present in a text file (with exceptions) (Python)

Tags: python

I want to get a list of all characters in a text file except for

```
[A-Z], [0-9], '|', '~'.
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried something on your own? If yes please post it here.

Comment: Edited to make a canonical title. Even if the question shows lack of effort, it should be of use to future readers.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991901/regular-expression-any-character-that-is-not-a-letter-or-number) stackoverflow question might help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Step 1*: Read in your file and convert it to a set of chars.

```
charset = set(open('file.txt').read())
```

*Step 2*: Join it back to a string with `str.join` for the next step.

```
chars = ''.join(charset)
```

*Step 3*: Using regex, substitute all characters that you do not want with `''`, then display

```
import re
filtered_chars = re.sub('[A-Z0-9|~]', '', chars)

print(set(filtered_chars))
```

---

Other references (similar to your use case but not quite):

1. [List of all unique characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902805/list-of-all-unique-characters-in-a-string)
2. [How to get all unique characters in a textfile? unix/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522234/how-to-get-all-unique-characters-in-a-textfile-unix-python)
3. [Regular Expression: Any character that is NOT a letter or number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991901/regular-expression-any-character-that-is-not-a-letter-or-number)

Comment: Thank you so much.